# Regular expression for validating UAE numbers

Tags: asp.net, validation, validation-controls

I need regex which validates UAE mobile phone number like

> +9710501234566 or
>
> +971 (050) (123 4566)

Currently I am using

```
^(\+971[\s]{0,1}[\-]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}|[\s]{0,1}0)(5[056]{1})[\s]{0,1}[\-]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{6}$
```

Could you help me please? I'm not really good with regular expressions...

Comment: Are there other possible ways to write the number apart from the 2 in your sample?

Comment: No,There could be the only 2 above formats

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\+971(\d{10}|\s\(\d{3}\)\s\(\d{3}\s\d{4}\))$");
```

Basically, you check for +971 as is, then either for 10 digits right after that, or the pattern space - left parenthesis - 3 digits - right parenthesis - space - left parenthesis - 3 digits - space - 4 digits - right parenthesis.

Note that since you mentioned the sample strings to be the only 2 patterns possible, I have used the literal characters '+','(' and ')' in my regex.

If you want to extend this to allow parentheses without space, just replace `\s` with `\s?` to make spaces optional.

Answer (score 2):

+971 (050) (123 4566) is invalid format
it should be +971 (50) (123 4566)

this will allow only number starting with
50 (etisalat) 
52 (du) 
55 (du) 
56 (etisalat)

```
/^5(0|2|5|6)\d{7}$/;
```

start with 5 and then matches either 0,2,5,6 and then 7 digits numbers
below also should work starting with 9715 format

```
/^+9715(0|2|5|6)\d{7}$/;
```