# How to build a regex pattern e.g. (+971) 556-123456 for HTML5 phone numbers?

Tags: html, regex

I need the pattern checking for mobile number in(+971) 556-123456 this format in HTML phone numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate UAE phone numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646890/regular-expression-for-validating-uae-numbers)

Comment: format is different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: is the `(+971)` prefix optional?

Comment: I think it should be (+971) 55-612-3456,plz Check it once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the RegEx you need:

```
\(\+971\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}
```

Here's a **[live DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wY3nF9/1)** of it.

And If I am not wrong the `+971` prefix is optional so the right RegEx would be:

```
(\+971)? [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}
```

And this is a **[live DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bX4yS7/1)** of it.

**EDIT:**

If the `+971` prefix is not optional and I assume the parentheses are optional, here's the RegEx you need:

```
\+971\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}
```

Make sure you add the `\s` to ensure having the space after the `+971` prefix.

This is a [**Working DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/kM5sZ4/2) and you can test it in the above snippet:

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Phone number:
  <input class="form-control" pattern="\+971\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}" name="homeNo" value="+971 555-4144" id="homeNo" required />

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: 971 is not optional and pattern is not working in jsp. pattern = "\(\+971)? [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}" maxlength="8" . but pattern is not working. Thanks for your response

Comment: How it doesn't work? What do you get? And if the 971 is not optional you can take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: I am using in HTML5. if I gave wrong format input, while I am submitting the form, I will get error message. but I am able to submit the form.This is my html 5 code . $(document).ready(function() {
$("#homeNo").jqxMaskedInput({ width: '100%', height: '100%', mask: '(+971) 5##-######'});
$('#mobileNo').attr("style","");}); <input class="form-control"   oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter valid homeNo')" pattern = "+971 [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}"   name="homeNo"  
               value ="${homeNo}"  id="homeNo" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" required />

Comment: please post your HTML5 code in an EDIT to the question.

Comment: Here's the HTML code for it: `Phone number: <input class="form-control"  pattern="\+971\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}" name="homeNo" value="+971 555-4144" id="homeNo"  required /><br>` I tested it and it works perfectly, take a look at the snippet in my EDIT.

Comment: yes. its working fine in your code. but I don't know why, its not working in my code. I am using jqwidgets, using that I am using some masking as well.I am not sure, that could be issue. see my code above.Thanks for your response.

Comment: Ok I see, but what are you getting in console? does it show any error?

Comment: No. I am not getting any errors in console.

Comment: Maybe you browser doesn't support HTML5 pattern?

Comment: <input class="form-control"  pattern="\(\+971\)\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}" id="mobileNo"  name="mobileNo" type="tel" 
               value ="${mobileNo}" required />its working fine with the below code: I just removed onvalid and oninvalid functions and its working fine now. Thanks for your effort. Thanks a ton.